# ¿Qué hace Clean and Build en netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

Tengo la duda de que hace el clean and build de netbeans.... lo sé su mismo nombre es muy descriptivo pero esque.... por accidente a un proyecto le di click en ese boton, se me fue el mouse hasta ahi, le di detener y ya... ese proyecto pesaba alrededor de 17 MB, pero ahora pesa nada mas 12 MB.... entonces tengo dudas sobre si fue la opción de clean and buld la que hizo eso y si hice mal en darle detener, si hice mal como afecta a mi proyecto?

Comment: Hace básicamente dos cosas: **1.** Elimina todos los archivos compilados previamente y otras salidas de compilación. **2.** Recompila la aplicación y crea un archivo JAR que contiene los archivos compilados. [Ver documentación](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html) Puesto que elimina archivos y crea otros, el tamaño del proyecto puede variar después de aplicar Clean and Build. ¿Hice mal en darle detener? No dañará tu proyecto, pero antes de hacer algo, piénsalo... no es bueno detener acciones bruscamente. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que hace es borrar las clases que han sido compiladas previamente y otros artefactos, luego reconstruye el proyecto entero desde cero.
Cuando tu utilizas esta opción (clean and build) las siguientes cosas occurren:

- Los directorios de salida que han sido generados son borrados (en la mayoría de los casos, son los directorios  `build` y `dist`)
- Los directorios `build` y `dist` son añadidos al directorio del proyecto (`PROJECT_HOME`).
- Todos los archivos fuentes son compilados en archivos `.class` y son colocados en el directorio `PROJECT_HOME/build`.
- Un archivo JAR conteniendo todo el proyecto es creado en el directorio `PROJECT_HOME/build`.
- Si has especificado cualquier librería para el proyecto (adicional al JDK) un directorio `lib` es creado  en el directorio `dist`. Las librerias son copiadas en `dist/lib`.
- El archivo manifiesto en el JAR es actualizado para incluir entradas que designan la clase principal (main) y cualquier libreria que estan en la ruta de clases (`classpath`) del proyecto.